# How to amend commit name and date of the last commit?

Tags: git

`git commit --amend --author="..."` only changes the author name but it doesn't change the commit name and date so they match up.  How can that be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

`git commit --amend` will open the commit into your editor, then you can amend the text.

or you can use

`--date`

`--message`